# Заявка на выделени?

Tags: склонение

Направляю заявку на выделени* транспорта для доставки

Answer (score 1):

На выделени**е**.

Даже не понимаю, что еще тут может быть.

Если "заявка на выделении транспорта" - это что-то марсианское. Заявка на выхлопных газах?